# Turn On/Off an external Alarm Light

Tags: java, usb, alarm

I have a large system with an Oracle DB, Java WebClient, and a few C# applications.

There is an event where the start time is written to the DB.  There is a minimum amount of time this event must run, and a maximun amount of time it is allowed to run.

The task is to have a simple alarm light, when an event is pass its minimnum time, the light will come on.

I have seen lots of simple alarm lights that plug into an USB port, but how can I turn them on and off from Java?

I have looked at the Philips Hue, looks like it has a manageable API to work with.  Does anybody have any expierence to share of working with Hue or other possible solutions??

Answer (score 0):

What about using Raspberry PI. It is cheaper than Philips Hue and there are many examples in internet you can find.

For instance: [How to connect LED](https://projects.drogon.net/raspberry-pi/gpio-examples/tux-crossing/gpio-examples-1-a-single-led/)

Comment: Philips is at a reasonable price (230 CHF or USD) for our enterprise.  I am looking for the 'easy' solution.  Rasberry PI, looks like it needs a bit more hardware knowledge and work to set it up.